# remove the line(object) in text file through console

Tags: java, list, file, object, java-io

I can't find out how I can remove through the console with surname a line from a text file. I have to write a surname out in the console and delete all records with this surname.
my file.txt

```
name surname data 11.11.1111
name1 surnama1 data1 12.12.2010
```

My Person class:

```
public class Person implements Serializable, Comparable<Person> {

    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public String secondName;
    public String age;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return age.equals(person.age) &&
                Objects.equals(name, person.name) &&
                surname.equals(person.surname) && secondName.equals(person.secondName);
    }
    getters,setters,toString , constructor here...

    public static Person parseRemove(String string) {
        String[] parts = string.split(" ");
        return new Person(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
    }

    compare here

    conparebySurname here
```

my Remove method, but its does not work well, and I don't know what I should fix here:

```
public static Boolean removeSurname() throws IOException {
        File file;
        String line;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<Person> res = new TreeSet<>();
        System.out.print("from which file: ");
        line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("which surname u need to delete ");
        String lineToRemove;
        String inLine = "";
        lineToRemove = in.nextLine();
        try {
            file = new File(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println();
        } catch (NullPointerException n) {
            System.err.println("no file");
            return false;
        }
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(line + ".txt");
        BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(line + ".txt", true));
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String strInfo;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((strInfo = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] arrInfo = strInfo.split(" ");
            res.add(new Person(arrInfo[0], arrInfo[1], arrInfo[2], arrInfo[3]));
            bufferWriter.write(strInfo) ;
        if(lineToRemove.equals(strInfo)){
                res.remove(strInfo); //???
//                bufferWriter.newLine();
                bufferWriter.flush();
            }
        }
        fis.close();
        reader.close();
        bufferWriter.close();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String surname = in.nextLine();

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("data.txt");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String strInfo;

        List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((strInfo = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] person = strInfo.split(" ");

            String personSurname = person[1];

            if (!surname.equals(personSurname))
                records.add(strInfo);
        }

        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.txt"));

        for (String record: records) {
            bufferedWriter.write(record + "\n");
        }

        bufferedWriter.flush();
    }
}
```

PS: You should create `bufferedWriter` only after you read all the data from the file. When you instantiate `bufferedWriter` object, it will make your file empty.